# Is there an English name for Piacenza (Italy)?

Tags: translation

Up until now, I believed that the city of Piacenza, Italy, had an English name, equal to its French name: "Plaisance".

However I've searched its article on Wikipedia, and I've noticed it's just called Piacenza.

So, was it ever called Plaisance in English, or it was just some sort of mistake I must have encountered somewhere?

Comment: Would it be IT here to ask _how_ did it happen to be named so, or would this be a question for History?

Comment: It would rather be a topic not for English but for Linguistics or Italian. ('pl' (Latin) > 'pi' (Italian) eg plaza -> piazza (very roughly)

Comment: @Mitch well definitely not for Italian, since my question would be _"Why this city is called in English with its French name?"_

Comment: Lohoris: I don't get that. You just said (which I as a native English speaker agree with) that the English word is the same as the Italian word.

Comment: @Mitch but SrJoven's answer, and even more Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment, suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia's [disambiguation page for Plaisance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaisance):

> Plaisance is a French word, meaning pleasantness, derived from the Latin placentia 'acceptable things'.

Among those links is to [Piacenza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piacenza), Italy. Wherein it states:

> Modern forms of the name descend from Latin Placentia. The etymology is long-standing, tracing an origin from the Latin verb, placēre, "to please." It is thus a "pleasant abode"

Wikipedia's note of transliteration:

> Latin Pl- becomes Italian Pi-; Latin -tia becomes Italian -za; however, the dialect form represents a slightly different regional development.

It would not be unreasonable to hear Pia (pya) vs Pla (pla) and confuse the two sounds.

See also Naples/Napoli and other cities.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a web search for Plaisance, Italy you get plenty of references to Piacenza.

Wikipedia tends toward hypercorrection with regard to place names, favoring the spelling in the original language,  probably due to the international scope of its readership.

Comment: Wikipedia does usually use the traditional English names of cities if those are fairly well-known (Warsaw and Copenhagen are not called _Warszawa_ and _København_ in their respective articles, for example). With less-known place names like Piacenza/Plaisence, there’s less proofreading and fewer editors, and thus less standardisation.